# how to store Gridview Boolean value in session variable and show another page in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

## GridView Page1 CodeBehinde1:

```
protected void  GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool Customs_Clearance = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[23].Text;
}

Session["customs_Clearance"] = Customs_Clearance;
```

And Page2 Which Show session GridView Data Code Behind:
*CheckBox*

```
CheckCustomClearance.Text=Session ["customs_Clearance"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the code below for your case.
I am assuming that the the column with index 23 is the boolean column and displayed as a checkbox column.

You can then always access in your other page `Session["customs_Clearance"]`.

```
protected void  GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //get selected row
   GridRow  selectedRow = GridView1.Rows[GridView1.SelectedIndex];

   //check if it's a checkbox column and set Session variable, if it is
   if(selectedRow.Cells[23].Controls[0] is CheckBox) {
     bool isChecked = (selectedRow.Cells[23].Controls[0] as CheckBox).Checked;
     Session["customs_Clearance"] = (isChecked == true ? "checked" : "unchecked");
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks it is working but when i showing the value in the browser it is show "True" not "Checked" the checkbox so please how to sort this problem

Comment: True is same Checked and False is same as Unchecked. What do you want to store in Session?

Comment: Use the updated code I have just changed. Remember a boolean type value in .Net is either true or false, and not checked or unchecked. So, first the boolean value is obtained and then it's converted to checked or unchecked according to your requirement.

Comment: You need read some basic documentation on CheckBox.Checked at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.checked(v=vs.110).aspx and notice whether Checked or UnChekcked is returned or true/false is returned by the Checked property of CheckBox.